# How to subscribe to a chain of Observables that contains a Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs, switchmap

I had a nested Observable situation, and after some research I found that it's best to use RxJS `switchMap`.

For my case the first observable contains a `Promise`, so I have to await the first subscription result before it's passed to the second observable. Now the second `Observable` is not being subscribed to and is returning an `Observable` instead of subscribing to its results.

```js
firstObservable(x) {
  return this.productService.getProduct(x).pipe(
    map(async result => {
       this.productObject = {...result};
       let timeVariable = await 
       this.distanceMatrixService.getTime(this.productObject, this.currentLocation);
       return this.productObject;
    })
}

async secondObservable(passedProductObject) {    
  const productObject = await passedProductObject;
  return this.productService.getProductsByShop(productObject.store_id).pipe(
    map(result => {
      ////STUFF that depends on the timeVariable 
    }));
} 

chainingObservables(x) {
  return this.firstObservable(x).pipe(
  switchMap(async x => this.secondObservable(x)));
}

this.chainingObservables(this.passedData).subscribe(res => {
 console.log("result", res);
})

result Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need any async/await. Try removing them and tell us if that works ?

Comment: `switchMap` works natively with Promises. In your `firstObservable` function, use `switchMap` instead of `map` and your code should work.

Comment: Solution using forkJoin: First, get rid of firstObservable and secondObservable and put all of this in one single method (see if it works and then try to refactor to makae it prettier)

    const observables: Observable<any>[] = []; // TODO: Change any to the known type
    observables.push(this.productService.getProduct(this.passedData));
    observables.push(this.productService.getProductsByShop(this.passedData)
    
    forkJoin(observables)
     .pipe(
      map(data => {
       // do your mapping stuff here
      })
     )

Comment: Hi, I actually need to await the result from the distanceMatrixService.getTime as it returns a promise. and to execute it I need to supply the result from the first subscription.

Comment: @Berkenus That's how switchMap works, it already handles that. No need for async/await.

Comment: @Berkanus if you need to do something only when both observables emits then use combineLatest

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot, I'll give it a try

Comment: @Random It worked perfectly, thanks. 
But instead I took your first advice literally and removed the Promise from the first observable and put it in the subscription block. So i'm using the distanceMatrixService.getTime after I get the results of both observables.

Comment: Looks good indeed, since you don't use the time in the first observable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use RxJS `from` function to convert the promise to an observable. After that a couple of `switchMap`s with `map` ought to suffice your requirement.

Try the following

```js
this.productService.getProduct(x).pipe(
  map(result => ({...result})),
  switchMap(productObject => 
    from(this.distanceMatrixService.getTime(productObject, this.currentLocation)).pipe(
      map(timeVariable => ({
        productObject: productObject,
        timeVariable: timeVariable
      }))
    )
  ),
  switchMap(({productObject, timeVariable}) =>
    this.productService.getProductsByShop(productObject.store_id).pipe(
      map(result => {
        // stuff that depends on `timeVariable`
      })
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log("result", res);
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a pipe chain using switchMap operator like this.

you should not use the async with observables

assuming this.distanceMatrixService.getTime returns a valid promise.

```
    observable(x) {
        return this.productService.getProduct(x).pipe(
            tap(result => {
                this.productObject = {...result};
            }),
            switchMap(() => {
                return from(this.distanceMatrixService.getTime(this.productObject, this.currentLocation))
                    .pipe(map((time) => [time, this.productObject]));
            }),
            switchMap(([time, passedProductObject]) => {
                return this.productService.getProductsByShop(passedProductObject.store_id).pipe(
                    map(result => {
                        ////STUFF that depends on the timeVariable
                        return time;
                    }));
            }));
    }

    subMethod(x) {
        this.observable(this.passedData).subscribe(res => {
            console.log('result', res);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was very helpful for my issue, but also for all my project, it taught me a great practice of how to structure my observables use in a clean way, especially the tap operator! thanks a lot